# Cosmos SDK returns empty results on a query without partition specified

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

.Net Cosmos SDK returns empty results on a query without partition specified. Works fine when partition key provided.

Did I miss something?

Code for iterating:

```
var iterator = this.cosmosLinqQuery.GetFeedIterator(queryable);

var results = new List<Entity>();

while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
     var result = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();

     results.AddRange(result.Resource);
}

return results;
```

Code for creating queryable:

```
var options = new QueryRequestOptions()
        {
            PartitionKey = PartitionKey.None,
            MaxItemCount = null,
            MaxConcurrency = -1,
            MaxBufferedItemCount = -1,
            EnableScanInQuery = true,
        };

IQueryable<Entity> queryable = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Entity>(
            requestOptions: options,
            continuationToken: continuationToken,
            allowSynchronousQueryExecution: true);
```

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Older versions would disable cross-partition queries by default.

Comment: Are the results empty after draining all pages? Or do you see some pages empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with setting the `PartitionKey` value to `PartitionKey.None` in your query options here:

```
    var options = new QueryRequestOptions()
    {
        PartitionKey = PartitionKey.None,
        MaxItemCount = null,
        MaxConcurrency = -1,
        MaxBufferedItemCount = -1,
        EnableScanInQuery = true,
    };
```

Based on my understanding, you use `PartitionKey.None` to get the documents that are created with no partition key (it is entirely possible to create a document without partition key). From the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.partitionkey.none?view=azure-dotnet#remarks):

> The returned object represents a partition key value that allows
> creating and accessing documents without a value for partition key

Can you try by removing `PartitionKey = PartitionKey.None` from your query request options? Something like:

```
var options = new QueryRequestOptions()
{
    MaxItemCount = null,
    MaxConcurrency = -1,
    MaxBufferedItemCount = -1,
    EnableScanInQuery = true,
};
```

Then you should be able to fetch all documents in a container.